# How to generate an aspx page after adding controls programmatic-ally?

Tags: asp.net

Consider a page called "page1.aspx"
I'm adding some controls to  this page programmatic-ally  ... 
What i need is to generate another copy for this page which should have the added controls in the "aspx" file not being added by code in the code behind file "aspx.cs" ..

the following example to clarify:-

Page1.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Page1.aspx.cs" Inherits="Page1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and the Page1.aspx.cs :-

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Page1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Controls.Add(new TextBox() { ID = "TextBox1" });
    }
}
```

what i need is to programmatic-ally create and save new page :-
Page2.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Page2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Page2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm intrigued as to why you need to do this...

Comment: Why can't you use Visual Studio to do this?

Comment: Answer for first comment :- The cause is to build a generator engine to create aspx pages instead of building them on run-time ...

Answer for second comment :- "NO COMMENT :)"